# How can I stop a joystick from controlling my mouse?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, mouse

How can I stop a joystick from controlling my mouse in Ubuntu 12.04?

I tried to remove `xserver-xorg-input-joystick` and `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-joystick`, both not installed.

Answer (score 1):

1- You should see your joystick number first ... so Run Terminal and type   xinpute list   ,and look to your joystick number and replace its number instead of the 10 in the Example below.

`#!/bin/bash
id=`xinput list | grep "↳ DragonRise Inc.   Generic   USB  Joystick     id=10" | cut -c58-59
`props_mouse=`xinput list-props 10 | grep "Generate Mouse Events (" | cut -c25-27
`props_teclado=`xinput list-props 10 | grep "Generate Key Events (" | cut -c23-25
`xinput set-prop 10 $props_mouse 0
xinput set-prop 10 $props_teclado 0`

2- Creat a new Document then put the code in it , then rename it to name.sh Format 
3- Run Terminal then put the path where you save the file .

Example :    cd Desktop      (Because i saved mine on the Desktop)

4- Type bash name.sh         ( Click Enter and You are Done ! )

Note1: to Turn it back on just change the 0 on the last 2 lines to  1 
Note2: if this doesn't work make sure to remove 
xserver-xorg-input-joystick and /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-joystick

Answer (score 0):

Taking from AhmedAlkaabi:

xinput may have more features now??

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$(xinput --list --id-only 'ZEROPLUS P4 Wired Gamepad')
source <(xinput list-props $id | perl -ne'
  if(m/Generate Mouse Events \(([0-9]+)\)/){print"props_mouse=$1;";}
  if(m/Generate Key Events \(([0-9]+)\)/){print"props_teclado=$1;";}
')
xinput set-prop $id $props_mouse 0
xinput set-prop $id $props_teclado 0
```

This is BASH, won't work is lesser shells.  Uses a bit of perl, but should not be too bad for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, you can create a file that contains

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "joystick catchall"
        MatchIsJoystick "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "joystick"
        Option "StartKeysEnabled" "False"  # Disable mouse events
        Option "StartMouseEnabled" "False" # Disable keyboard events
EndSection
```

*(Taken from [→ here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Gamepad#Disable_joystick_from_controlling_mouse)).*

Answer (score 0):

**For me, the issue turned out to be Steam!**

By default, Steam makes your gamepad control the mouse cursor, which is super annoying if you're trying to play browser-based gamepad games, since Steam thinks that's the "desktop" config.

To disable that, go into Steam Settings, then "Controller", then click on "Desktop Configuration".

Next, click on "Browse Configs" and choose "Disabled".

Finally, click on "Apply Configuration" and then "Done".

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Mike's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198200) on this same page, here is a more portable-shell version, without perl, and offered as a function.

```
jsinput() {
    # Insert your controller name here, as seen from `xinput --list`.
    _c="$( xinput --list --id-only 'Logic3 Controller' )"
    # Default is off, unless you pass "yes" or similar as first parameter.
    _mode="0" ; echo "${1}" | grep -qiE '\<(yes|1|y|on)\>' && _mode=1
    # Find ids of these property names, and then tell each one to go to the mode chosen in the previous line.
    xinput list-props "${_c}" | sed -n -r -e '/Generate (Mouse|Key)/{s/.*\(([0-9]+)\).*/\1/;p}' | xargs -I@ xinput set-prop "${_c}" @ "${_mode}"
}
```

If you stick this in your `~/.bashrc` you could then run `jsinput` to disable this controller as mouse input. To turn on mouse input you could then simply run `jsinput 1` or `jsinput on`.